# Select inner join many-to-one relationship limiting number of results for child table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have the following tables:

```
create table TableA (
    Id int primary key identity,
    Name varchar(80) not null
)

create table TableB (
    Id int primary key identity,
    TableA_Id int not null foreign key references TableA(Id),
    Value varchar(80) not null
)
```

I would like to write a query similar to

```
select TableA.Name, TableB.Value
    from TableA
    inner join TableB on TableA.Id = TableB.TableA_Id
    where TableA.Name like 'a%'
    order by TableB.Value asc
```

except that I want only the top 10 within each `TableA_Id` of `TableB.Value` (ordered by `TableB.Value` ascending).

Instead of returning every `TableB.Value` of each `TableA.Name`, I want only the top 10 values of each `TableA.Name`.

What would be such a query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx).

A `CROSS APPLY` allows you to

- Use a `TOP` in the subselect
- Use an `ORDER BY` in the subselect
- Match each row of the outer select with every matching row from the subselect

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  TableA.Name
        , b.Value
FROM    TableA
        CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT  TOP 10 *
          FROM    TableB
          WHERE   TableA.Id = TableB.TableA_Id
          ORDER BY
                  TableB.Value
        ) b
WHERE   TableA.Name LIKE 'a%'
```

Comment: @Lamak - Something I've picked up only recently from gbn & martin.